# Having trouble with 2-way binding using a dependency property and another property in a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf

My solution has two projects: one is called `ChartControl` and the other is `LineGridViewCh4`. LineGridViewCh4 contains the view and viewmodel that uses the control `ChartControl`. I can change the property `Lines` and the view gets updated and updates the `Lines` dependency property and `Lines` property in `ChartStyle.cs`. This is working fine. What I want to make happen is communication in the other direction. For example. If the `Lines` property were to change (by mousedown in the red square to set the `Lines` property to 3) in `ChartStyle.cs`, I'd like to have the property `Lines` (in `ChartStyle.cs`) update the dependency property in `LineChart.xaml.cs` and the change reflected in the view `LineGridControlView.xaml`. I tried creating a binding statement in the ctor of `LineChart.xaml.cs` but I'm not sure how to do this or if this is the right approach. In `LineChart.xaml.cs` method `SetLineChart()` has a statement `cs.Line = Line;` and can only work in one direction. It seems like I need `Line = cs.Line;` somewhere for the reverse direction. Any help would be appreciated.

ChartStyle.cs

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChartControl.ChartModel
{
    public class ChartStyle : BindableBase
    {
        public Canvas ChartCanvas { get; set; }

        public double Lines { get; set; }

        public void AddChartStyle()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Lines; i++)
            {
                double dx = i * 10; 
                Line gridline = new Line();
                gridline.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                gridline.StrokeThickness = 4;
                gridline.X1 = new Point(dx, 0).X;
                gridline.Y1 = new Point(dx, 0).Y;
                gridline.X2 = new Point(dx, 100).X;
                gridline.Y2 = new Point(dx, 100).Y;
                ChartCanvas.Children.Add(gridline);
            }

            Rectangle setLines = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 2                
            };
            setLines.Width = 30;
            setLines.Height = 30;
            Canvas.SetTop(setLines, 110);
            ChartCanvas.Children.Add(setLines);

            setLines.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(SetLines_MouseDown);
        }

        private void SetLines_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is Rectangle)
            {
                Lines = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LineChart.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChartControl.Views.LineChart"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
            <Grid >
                <Canvas Name="chartCanvas"/>
            </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

LineChart.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using ChartControl.ChartModel;

namespace ChartControl.Views
{
    public partial class LineChart : UserControl
    {
        private ChartStyle cs;

        public LineChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cs = new ChartStyle();
            cs.ChartCanvas = chartCanvas;

            //Binding csLine = new Binding("Lines");
            //csLine.Source = cs.Lines;
            //Lines.SetBinding(LinesProperty, csLine);
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            SetLineChart();
        }

        private void SetLineChart()
        {
            cs.Lines = Lines;

            RedrawLineChart();
        }

        private void RedrawLineChart()
        {
            chartCanvas.Children.Clear();
            cs.AddChartStyle();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty LinesProperty =
                      DependencyProperty.Register("Lines", typeof(int),
                      typeof(LineChart),
                      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(12, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                         FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public int Lines
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(LinesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LinesProperty, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

LineGridControlView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="LineGridViewCh4.Views.LineGridControlView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChartControl.Views;assembly=ChartControl"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Height="220" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Lines" Width="60" Height="25"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbLines" Width="50" Height="25" Text="{Binding Lines, ElementName=myChart}"/>
                <Button Content="Set" Command="{Binding ChangeLinesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbLines}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <local:LineChart x:Name="myChart" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

LineGridControlViewModel.cs

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;

namespace LineGridViewCh4.ViewModels
{
    public class LineGridControlViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public DelegateCommand<string> ChangeLinesCommand { get; set; }

        public LineGridControlViewModel()
        {
            ChangeLinesCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(ChangeLines);
        }

        private int lines;
        public int Lines
        {
            get { return lines; }
            set { SetProperty(ref lines, value); }
        }
        public void ChangeLines(string numberOfLines)
        {
            Lines = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfLines);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `PropertyChangedCallback Delegate`, which represents the callback that is invoked when the effective property value of a dependency property changes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: The suggestion doesn't seem to solve my problem. I want mouse interaction in `ChartStyle.cs` to change the dependency property in addition to my view changing the dependency property which currently works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this problem through inheritance. My base class is `UserControl` which `ChartStyle` now inherits from. Below are the changes:

ChartStyle.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChartControl.ChartModel
{
    public class ChartStyle : UserControl
    {
        public Canvas ChartCanvas { get; set; }

        public static DependencyProperty LinesProperty =
              DependencyProperty.Register("Lines", typeof(int),
              typeof(ChartStyle),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                  12, 
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
                  new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

        public int Lines
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(LinesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LinesProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChartStyle cs = sender as ChartStyle;
            if (e.Property == LinesProperty)
                cs.Lines = (int)e.NewValue;
        }

        public void AddChartStyle()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Lines; i++)
            {
                double dx = i * 10; 
                Line gridline = new Line();
                gridline.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
                gridline.StrokeThickness = 4;
                gridline.X1 = new Point(dx, 0).X;
                gridline.Y1 = new Point(dx, 0).Y;
                gridline.X2 = new Point(dx, 100).X;
                gridline.Y2 = new Point(dx, 100).Y;
                ChartCanvas.Children.Add(gridline);
            }

            Rectangle setLines = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = Brushes.Red,
                StrokeThickness = 2                
            };
            setLines.Width = 30;
            setLines.Height = 30;
            Canvas.SetTop(setLines, 110);
            ChartCanvas.Children.Add(setLines);

            setLines.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(SetLines_MouseDown);
        }

        private void SetLines_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is Rectangle)
            {
                Lines = 3;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LineChart.xaml.cs

```
using ChartControl.ChartModel;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ChartControl.Views
{
    public partial class LineChart : ChartStyle
    {
        public LineChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChartCanvas = chartCanvas;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            RedrawLineChart();
        }

        private void RedrawLineChart()
        {
            chartCanvas.Children.Clear();
            AddChartStyle();
        }
    }
}
```

LineChart.xaml

```
<local:ChartStyle x:Class="ChartControl.Views.LineChart"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChartControl.ChartModel"     
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
            <Grid >
                <Canvas Name="chartCanvas"/>
            </Grid>
</local:ChartStyle>
```